# checking if a string input lies between a range

Tags: string, python-3.x

I coded a small  program that checks if the sting input is a positive integer and if it is, then whether it lies within specific range of string. Here is my code:

```
def num_check(n:str):
   if n.isdigit() == True:
      if n in '1,2,3,4,5,6,7':
         print('The integer lies between 1 and 7')
      else:
         print('Try again')
   else:
      print('Invalid input')
```

Is there a way that I can avoid hard coding the range(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the number to an integer, and see if it is less than 1. If so, return `False`. Otherwise, check if it is in the range of the `min` and `max` by using the built-in `range()`. `range(7, 10)` returns `[7, 8, 9]`. If so, return `True`. If not, return `False`.

```
def num_check(n, min, max):
    n = int(n)
    if n < 1:
        return False
    if n in range(min, max+1):
        return True
    return False
```

This runs as:

```
>>> num_check('8', 9, 17)
False
>>> num_check('8', 3, 17)
True
>>> num_check('-1', 3, 17)
False
>>> num_check('-1', -5, 17)
False
>>>
```

Comment: Is these a way we can keep Strings and not Ints? nm...I see it now.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it as:

```
def num_check(n,min,max):
   if n.isdigit() == True:
      if int(n) in range(min,max+1):
         print('The integer lies between {} and {}'.format(min, max))
      else:
         print('Try again')
   else:
      print('Invalid input')
```

Comment: Its still giving me incorrect results. num_check('-1',1,6) results in Try again.

Comment: @user3233949, Well yeah. -1 is not between 1 and 6